# Ошибка при использвании картинок в выдвижном меню

Tags: android, android-navigation-drawer

Выдвижное меню работает как надо и но напоролся на такой графический артефакт : [image: Как видите проблема в том , что картинки есть но не полностью]
Это мобильный терминал и как получить скрины с него Я без понятия) Что делать? Картинки просто загружал :

```
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_scan"
        android:icon="@mipmap/scan_rfid_icon_foreground"
        android:title="Scan" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_read"
        android:icon="@mipmap/read_rfid_icon_foreground"
        android:title="Read" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/nav_write"
        android:icon="@mipmap/write_rfid_icon_foreground"
        android:title="Write" />
```

Лучше пытаться через код или через разметку?

Comment: Непонятно о какой проблеме идёт речь) На картинке иконки видны. В чём с ними проблема?

Comment: @ЮрийСПб Это проблема) Виден контур картинки,а не сама картинка) там должна быть нормальная картинка с цветом, и тд, а не вот это вот, словно вырезали с кнопки)

Comment: Вроде как это как раз нормально. Если хотите полного контроля над внешним видом- берите RecyclerView вместо NavigationView. Это в разы сложнее, но пытаться внешний вид меню менять ещё хуже

Comment: @ЮрийСПб окай попробую

Comment: картинки в векторе или png? Если вектор, то попробуйте воспользоваться сторонними сервисами для перегонки их в xml, например http://inloop.github.io/svg2android/

Comment: Не знаю что такое мобильный терминал, но: если вы пользуетесь эмулятором то у вас как минимум два способа сделеть норм скрины: через "PreeenScreen" c зажатым "Alt" - или через настройки эмулятора. Если же просто в устройстве, вам никто не мешает зажать "-громкость + кнопка включения" на более новом андроиде есть в шторке или в меню отключения кнопка: сделать "Print Screen". Во вторых: вам попробовать воспользоваться вектором, скачайте отсюда любые иконки: https://material.io/tools/icons/ и попробуйте их. Тут svg делать так: https://developer.android.com/studio/write/vector-asset-studio#svg